# PDO login validation

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement, bcrypt

**I am trying to create a user login verification script. I have two pages one is called checklogin.php which is the code bellow :**

```
<?php 
session_start();

$host="localhost"; // Host name
$username="root"; // Mysql username
$password="testdbpass"; // Mysql password
$db_name="test"; // Database name
$table = "users";

// Connect to server via PHP Data Object
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;", $username, $password);

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];


if(isset($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['username']) 
AND
isset($_POST['password']) && !empty($_POST['password']))

$pass = crypt($password . $row['salt']);
$statement->bindParam(':username', $username);
$query = ("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE username = :username");
$statement = $db->prepare($query);
$output = 'Login Error';

if ($statement->execute() && $row = $statement->fetch())

{
    if ($row['password'] === $pass)

        {
        if ( $row['activated'] !== 0 ) {
        $output = 'Not activiated wait for Administrator Approval';
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        }
        $output = 'Logged In';
        }
    }

    echo $output;

   $db = null;
   ?>
```

**and I have a register_script.php page which is this code :**

```
<?php 

$host="localhost"; // Host name
$username="root"; // Mysql username
$password="testdbpass"; // Mysql password
$db_name="test"; // Database name

// Connect to server via PHP Data Object
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;", $username, $password);

CRYPT_BLOWFISH or die ('No Blowfish found.');

//This string tells crypt to use blowfish for 15 rounds.
$Blowfish_Pre = '$2y$15$';
$Blowfish_End = '$';

// Blowfish accepts these characters for salts.
$Allowed_Chars =
'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789./';
$Chars_Len = 63;


$Salt_Length = 45;
$salt = "";

for($x=0;$x<5000;$x++)
{
$salt .= $Allowed_Chars[mt_rand(0,$Chars_Len)];
}
$bcrypt_salt = $Blowfish_Pre . $salt . $Blowfish_End;

$password = $_POST['password'];

$hashed_password = crypt($password, $bcrypt_salt);

// Insert statements with PDO 

try {
$query = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO `users_blowfish` (username, email,   fname, lname,   salt, password) 
                           VALUES (:username, :email,   :first, :last, :salt, :hash)");

    $params = array(
                    'username' => $_POST['username'],
                    'email' => $_POST['email'], 
                    'first' => $_POST['fname'],
                    'last' => $_POST['lname'],
                    'salt' => $bcrypt_salt,
                    'hash' => $hashed_password);

        $query->execute($params);

}

catch (PDOException $e) {
    error_log($e->getMessage());
    die("An error occured, contact admin");
}

$dbh= null;

?>

 <html>
<body>
    <p> 
        Thank you for registering your account. Please wait for   administrator approval before doing anything else. Thank you - System Administrator. 
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

I try to login and I am getting a error log in my apache2 error file state :

**[Sat Dec 22 11:47:36 2012] [error] [client Desktop] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /var/www/version2/checklogin.php on line 23, referer: **`http://localhost/version2/`****

I can't seem pinpoint the problem with this. I have referenced php.net on how to work with PDO but to no avail. The problem is being caused by the checklogin.php as the register_script.php is working fine (tested from a couple days ago).
Any help would be lovely thank you.

Edit 1:

Line 23 goes as fallows : `$statement->bindParam(':username', $username);`

Edit 2:  Lines that could be causing the problem :

```
`$pass = crypt($password . $row['salt']);
 $statement->bindParam(':username', $username);
 $query = ("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE username = :username");
 $statement = $db->prepare($query);
 $output = 'Login Error';`
```

Comment: Would you show us what's at line 23 so we don't have to count down the lines?  :)

Comment: Sure would be helpful if SO gave us line numbers in the code snippet feature!

Comment: I do not find a parse error in the code posted above. Line 23 says this: $statement->bindParam(':username', $username);

Comment: Just edited the post @RayPaseur

Comment: Just a note, but when you use empty() you don't need to also check isset() in the same conditional as empty() will do that as well.

Comment: just edited the post @RonaldBarzell

Comment: So the parse error is fixed now?  In general whdn a parse error says, "unexpected" there is something wrong above the line with the error.  Common issues are missing quotes, semi-colons, parentheses, etc.

Comment: @RayPaseur I keep receiving the parse error even with antoyo's input.

Comment: I was missing a ) on line 22 where my $pass is created

Comment: Please post the script (the ENTIRE script) that has the parse error.

Comment: If you want to save some time, this article shows the general design pattern.  You can start with that and then add your own touches such as use of PDO and Blowfish.  http://www.experts-exchange.com/Web_Development/Web_Languages-Standards/PHP/A_2391-PHP-login-logout-and-easy-access-control.html

Comment: @RayPaseur I just updated the script. I don't know why the line above wasn't originally pasted

Comment: There is no parse error in the script posted above for checklogin.php  Are you sure you're testing the right version of the scripts?

Comment: I'm absolutely positive. the version1 hasn't been touched in weeks. been working on version2 for a while now. it can't be the other version.

Answer (score 3):

You are using $db->prepare() twice, but you should only use it once, like this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE username = :username";
$statement = $db->prepare($query);
```

And make sure you did not forget curly braces for this condition:

```
if(isset($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['username']) 
AND
isset($_POST['password']) && !empty($_POST['password']))
```